# How to read Twitter feeds

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, twitter

I've used this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/35668/How-to-Read-Twitter-Feeds-With-LINQ-to-XML.aspx) to retrieve my twitter feeds however it has an error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using a library that abstracts all the parsing for you.

Try [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/), a .NET library designed for quick and easy Twitter integration.

There is a large set of [documentation on the Twitterizer API](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/), and sample code. Perhaps get a feel for how others are using it by [browsing the Twitterizer tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitterizer).

Comment: I tried the Twitterizer, I added the dll's and when I tried to instantiate a mwthod for example this one TwitterUser t = new TwitterUser(); and I build it, it has an error the namespace could not be found.

Comment: The namespace issue is probably because your project is building for the client profile. You should change it to build for the full .net framework.

Comment: Also: You shouldn't instantiate a TwitterUser directly. The TwitterUser class has static methods for each of the API endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried manually going to "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/" + User + ".rss" in your browser, and seeing if you get a 400 error there? I'm guessing a typo in your user name when you call `Twitter.Parse(UserName)`;

Comment: its not consistent sometimes it displays and sometimes its not. Here's the error Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour