# Twitter API get user feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read Twitter feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800850/how-to-read-twitter-feeds)

I am looking for some samples to get the twitter feed (public feed) for an user in C#, ASP.NET. Whatever samples I found are using OAuth etc, but I am not able to find any sample which provides just feed without any authentication.

Any sample is highly appricated.

PS: I don't want to use the twitter widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just read through the Twitter API documentation and to fetch the feed from a user with API 1.1 you need User Level Access rights which you can only get through having a valid OAuth authentification so unless you decide to implement OAuth you will receive this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

You can still use the API 1.0 but be aware that it already is deprecated and will probably be removed in the future. If you want to use the API 1.0, this is the appropriate URL to call:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=USERNAME_GOES_HERE&count=NUMBER_OF_TWEETS_GOES_HERE

I'd suggest you implement OAuth (it's not that hard) and start using the API 1.1.

Comment: Are you sure about API 1.1 requires OAuth to retrieve the public feed? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline, this link doesn't say anything about that

Comment: Tippu: Look closer at the right hand side. "Authentication Requires user context"

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the RSS feed of the user
example: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=cnn
you just have to replace screen_name variable

Comment: I read that the RSS feeds will be deprecated by March 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If using TweetSharp.dll you may use following:

```
var service = new TweetSharp.TwitterService();
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = 
    service.ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline("@rudolf_franek");
```